# check inventory_hostname inside loop

Tags: ansible

I try to do some action inside a loop, only when the hostname has a special format.
But the task gets skipped all the time.

```
- name: debug
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ list }}"
  when: inventory_hostname is not match("ld*")
```

Is it possible to do that somehow?

Comment: Your syntax looks ok, you are sur that is a "not" expression you want? In your code, debug run for all hostname that no start with "ld", that's it?

Comment: yes, i want a not expression.

Comment: Look like you just forgot the dot in `"ld.*"`?  yours matches `'l' followed by 0+ times 'd'`; in any case I'd add string terminators (`"^ld.*$"`)

Comment: But without the loop it work's as expected.

Comment: since the when does not test on "item", you will get all items in the list or not depending on inventory_hostname, so cant see how the loop affects it at all